# Not able to display category wise products on home page

Tags: category, products, category-products, home

I wan to display category wise products on homepage like the image below
[image]

And i am referring [this link](http://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-display-products-from-the-category-on-the-home-page.html#gref).

And using below code to do that. But it is not working.
Can someone please guide me how do i achieve this.

```
{{block type="catalog/product_new" category_id="5" column_count="4" products_count="3" name="home.catalog.product.new" alias="product_homepage" template="catalog/product/widget/new/content/new_list.phtml"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have using magento1.X version.

And already applied magento patch [SUPEE-6788](https://magento.com/security/patches/supee-6788),then you need to remove catalog/product_new from  whitelist

1. `System > Permissions > Blocks`
2. Add New Block
3. Block Name: `catalog/product_new`
4. Is Allowed : Yes

Comment: I have checked that it shows `Status: Allowed` for `catalog/product_new`
when i am using the code example i have given in my question, it shows me the data but it shows all the products that are begin entered in the admin panel for any category.

Instead it should show only category_id="5" products only.

Comment: My homepage is custom homepage added my me.